# Unique data frame but keep complete cases

Tags: r

I have a `data frame` as below:

```
df1
ID    NAME   LOCATION
101   Jack   Netherlands
102   Jack     NA
104   Tom      NA
105   Tom     
123   Sam     
124   Sam      NA
134   Dan     
135   Dan    Germany
```

I would like to have an output like this:

```
df2
ID    NAME   LOCATION
101   Jack   Netherlands
104   Tom      NA
124   Sam      NA
135   Da     Germany
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `df2 <- df1[complete.cases(df1),]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have two types of missing data, some marked `NA` (which you still consider "complete") and some marked `""` (which you want to omit).

The R convention is opposite from yours - rows with `NA` are *not* considered complete, but the empty string `""` is perfectly valid data. I would recommend you **match R's convention while using R** - replace the `NA` values in your data frame with a string (maybe `"missing"`, or `"not applicable"`), and replace the empty strings in your data with `NA` since you consider them missing. Then `complete.cases` will work perfectly for you as suggested in the comments, `df2 <- complete.cases(df1)`

You can use the `replace` function to make these changes to your data column. If your data column is a `factor`, you could may instead edit the levels (or just convert it to `character` and use the `replace` function). If you share your data reproducibly with `dput()` ([see here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061)) I'll be happy to show some  more explicit code, but as-is I'm not sure of the structure and underlying classes in your data.